# How can my Maven project run both JUnit and TestNG without TestNG trying to run JUnit tests?

Tags: java, maven, junit, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a Maven project in which I am required to execute both JUnit and TestNG tests. My `pom.xml` has setup the Maven Surefire plugin as follows:

```
<!-- ... -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
    <threadCount>1</threadCount>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
<!-- ... -->
```

Unfortunately, when I execute my unit tests using Surefire, all tests are correctly executed, but TestNG appears to be trying to execute the JUnit tests a second time, and an exception like the following is appearing in the logs.

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Failure in JUnit mode for class com.hotwire.api.pricing.impl.PricingConfigIT: could not create/run JUnit test suite: 
Cannot find JUnit method class junit.framework.TestSuite$1.warning
at org.testng.junit.JUnitTestRunner.runFailed(JUnitTestRunner.java:239)
at org.testng.junit.JUnitTestRunner.start(JUnitTestRunner.java:232)
at org.testng.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:213)
at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:672)
at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1003)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:703)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1170)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1095)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:132)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:198)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:94)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:147)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
```

How can I prevent this exception from polluting my logs?

Answer (score 5):

I thought that I would share my answer because it took a little while to figure out and my particular problem is somewhat different than the problems of others who have encountered this particular stack trace.

The solution is to add the following XML element to Surefire's configuration in the `pom.xml` file.

```
<configuration>
  <!-- pre-existing config -->
  <properties>
    <property>
      <name>junit</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>
  </properties>
</configuration>
```

This is documented further in the [Surefire documentation on running JUnit and TestNG tests together](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Running_TestNG_and_JUnit_Tests).